# Run command on multiple files and alter the output file name base off of input file

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I wish to perform piped commands on multiple files in a directory.

```
grep -r Chr18 C* |  awk '$2>=1600000&&$2<=1700000'  > nameDependentOnInputFile.txt
```

Every file I desire to run the command on begins with a C so I should be able to use * to run the command on all those files. How can I alter the output file name based on the input file? I've also seen that I could overwrite the initial file but that is undesirable.

Comment: Are the files in the same directory?  Are they all text files (C.txt) and are you trying to get `$2` # between 160000-170000?

Comment: Yes all files are in the same directory and they are all cov_af files...but output should be .txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you are trying to print only those files in a directory where `$2` is between 160000 and 170000 then something like the below should work:

```sh
for f in /path/to/files/*.cov_af ; do
 bname=`basename $f`
 pref=${bname%%.txt}
awk '$2 >= 160000 && $2 <= 170000' $f > /path/to/store/output/${pref}_new.txt
done
```

Comment: If you're going to use `basename`, you may as well go for `pref=$(basename "$f" .txt)` and save yourself a line. `basename` can strip a suffix by itself. Otherwise I'd suggest `bname=${f##*/}; pref=${bname%.txt}`. Don't forget to quote your variables as well.

Comment: The solution worked great!! and I did use the above comments suggestion

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and I'm glad it worked :).